# how can i set my side menu should be starts from right side in place of left?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

[image: Side menu screen which starts from left side]

I want to try side menu screen should be start from right side in place of left. Could you please tell me changes for same ? How it is possible . See the image it is coming from left side . But i want it should be start from right side .

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import handyman.com.handyman.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import handyman.com.handyman.model.NavDrawerItem;
public class Profile extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[]   navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

       TextView hi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hi);
       /* getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);*/
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();


        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        /*ActionBar setSupportActionBar;
         setSupportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);*/





        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name )
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                mDrawerList.bringToFront();
                mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }



    }



    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {


            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new MyOrders();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new MyWallet();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new RateCard();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new Offers();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new Help();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new Notifi();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        this.finish();

    }
  /*  @Override
    public void onBackpressed()
    {
        //super.onBackPressed();
        this.finish();

    }*/
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Profile"
    android:id="@+id/app_name">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="Hi user"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:divider="@color/list_divider"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector"
                android:background="@color/list_background"/>
        </FrameLayout>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:background="@color/list_background"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what do you mean. do you want to open side menu from right side instead of left ?

Comment: @MikeM. did not work.

Comment: @MikeM. yes not working

Answer (score -1):

```
 try this:
   SimpleSideDrawer slide_me;
    slide_me = new SimpleSideDrawer(this);
        slide_me.setRightBehindContentView(R.layout.your layout);//(Fix your layout width)
       menubutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                slide_me.toggleRightDrawer();
            }
        });
         @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (slide_me.isClosed() == false) {
        slide_me.close();
    } else {

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: this type of sliding menu working for me and support all versions of android  that is why i am posting this answer here if the answer is not suitable please omit that don't put negative vote @user6313669

Comment: i have not put someone else put negative comment . But could you please tell me where i have to put your code?

Comment: <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout> do naot need this with out this create your layout and where you want to implement (which Activity) there@user6313669

Answer (score -2):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_gravity="Left"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

make drawer layout in right gravity you can open it from right side .

Comment: and if you want to make right side image make custom image and inflate it in listview

Comment: its not worked. I have not put ant negative comment .